# R ggplot function error

Tags: r, ggplot2

My name is Venus , I am a beginner of data mining and use R. Right now, I need fill my datas to map and show it with different colours to see the different level.

I have install ggplot library and input my data with longtitue and latitude

My code like this

```
> ggplot(target_map, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = Target.rate)) + 
+   geom_polygon(colour = alpha("black", 1/2), size = 0.2) +
+   geom_polygon(data = needregion, colour ="white", fill = NA)+
+   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuRd")
```

I do this from an example, but I don't know why R always return this result:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (19584): x, y, group, fill

So, Could you give me some suggest what wrong with me? Thank you a lot

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide part of your data for us to reproduce your error.

Comment: try editing your post include the output of `dput(target_map)` and `dput(needregion)`

Comment: Hi Nathan, I have dput(target_map):    
    29.947198, 29.6056145, 29.928778, 29.7604267, 29.9183051, 
    29.8714057, 29.945433, 29.933603, 30.0056201, 29.9339177, 
    29.8232645, 29.9340025, 29.8922554, 29.7604267, 29.7604267
    )), .Names = c("region", "long.x", "lat.x", "group", "order", 
"subregion", "NAME", "school.level", "Target.rate", "Student.score", 
"Number.Score", "PERCENTAGE", "White", "Black", "Asian", "Hispanic", 
"Economically.disadvantaged", "School.rate", "long.y", "lat.y"
), row.names = c(NA, -19584L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: And the following is the output of dput(needregion):     NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
)), .Names = c("long", "lat", "group", "order", "region", "subregion"
), row.names = 123:208, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Hi Kitman0804: The data I used is :

Comment: @user7083472 Um. It seems that you didn't copy the whole output of `dput`. If you don't want to reveal all data, you can try `dput(head(target_map), 10)` and `dput(head(needregion), 10)` for showing the first ten rows only.

Comment: I would also suggest to start simple.  What happens if you do ```ggplot(target_map, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +   geom_polygon()``` ?

Comment: @kitman0804 My output of head(needregion) is :  head(needregion)
         long      lat group order region subregion
123 -94.03956 29.70786     1   123  texas      <NA>
124 -94.06821 29.70786     1   124  texas      <NA>
125 -94.32031 29.61046     1   125  texas      <NA>
126 -94.36042 29.59327     1   126  texas      <NA>
127 -94.38334 29.58754     1   127  texas      <NA>
128 -94.42918 29.57608     1   128  texas      <NA>
>

Comment: @kitman0804  My resut of head(target_map)   region    long.x  lat.x group order subregion    NAME school.level Target.rate Student.score Number.Score PERCENTAGE  White  Black  Asian Hispanic

Comment: @ kitman0804   1  texas -94.49792 33.667     1     1      <NA>                ALDINE H S         high   0.2475476    0.50704630   0.53071540     0.8206 0.0179 0.0874 0.0112   0.8789
2  texas -94.49792 33.667     1     1      <NA>             ALDINE MIDDLE       middle   0.1777265    0.07362669   0.07037325     0.8872 0.0140 0.1800 0.0040   0.8000
Economically.disadvantaged School.rate    long.y    lat.y
1                      0.799    0.111111 -95.40822 29.91682
2                      0.776    0.333333 -95.35533 29.93372

Comment: @kitman0804  I am sorry I copy the code in so many comment, But thank you for your help

Comment: Why don't you use "edit" to include your codes/output in the question? And it is better to copy the results `dput(head(target_map),  some_number)` and `dput(head(needregion), some_number)`

Comment: And what happen if you change the third line to `geom_polygon(data = needregion, aes(colour ="white", fill = NA))`

Comment: Also, I have found that there is no `long` and `lat` in your data `target_map` but `long.x`, `long.y`, `lat.x` and `lat.y`.

Comment: @kitman0804, Hi Kitman,   yeah, I need to use is long.y and lat.y. But when I change my code like this:  ggplot(target_map, aes(x=long.y, y =lat.y, group = group)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill = Target.rate), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) +
+   geom_polygon(data = needregion, aes(colour ="white", fill = NA))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'long.y' not found                         It still shows me an error says object'long.y'not found

Comment: I guess there is no `long.y` and `lat.y` in `needregion`. Try `geom_polygon(data = needregion, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, colour ="white", fill = NA))`

Comment: Did you try @Ott Toomet 's code?

Comment: @Ott Toomet   I use the code from Ott Toomet :ggplot(target_map, aes(long, lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon()  But it still return an  Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (19584): x, y, group

Comment: @kitman00804, do you mean the code: ggplot(target_map, aes(x = long.y, y = lat.y, group = group, fill = Target.rate)) + geom_polygon(colour = alpha("black", 1/2), size = 0.2) +
  geom_polygon(data = needregion, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, colour ="white", fill = NA))    But I don't know why R return to me: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: What are your variable names?  Can you show ```head(target_map)```?